# Why has ruby-jwt stopped decoding JWTs after updating the gem from 1.3.0 to 2.2.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, jwt

I have an issue with my implementation of ruby-jwt after updating:

- Rails 4.1.6 to 4.2.11.3
- Ruby 2.1.4 to 2.6.6
- ruby-jwt gem from 1.3.0
  to 2.2.2.

It will not decode the Token after the update and returns the 'Invalid login information.' error message from the `Login` class `decode` method.

This is the log from a successful login on the original version:

```
2020-12-04T09:51:42.814533+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-04T09:51:42.814461 #8]  INFO -- : Started POST "/api/p/v1/users/verify" for 54.210.159.54 at 2020-12-04 09:51:42 +0000
2020-12-04T09:51:42.859735+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-04T09:51:42.859575 #8]  INFO -- : Processing by API::P::V1::UsersController#verify as JSON
2020-12-04T09:51:42.859766+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-04T09:51:42.859707 #8]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"login"=>"long token....................."}
2020-12-04T09:51:43.483446+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/p/v1/users/verify" host=rails-api-app.herokuapp.com request_id=7f6dbb16-df78-4714-9b7c-b984905a2d6b fwd="54.210.159.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=674ms status=200 bytes=1457 protocol=https
2020-12-04T09:51:43.481107+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-04T09:51:43.481016 #8]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 621ms (Views: 477.0ms | ActiveRecord: 25.7ms)
```

And here is the response I get after I've built the updated app on Heroku:

```
2020-12-04T09:48:11.749514+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-04T09:48:11.749444 #16]  INFO -- : Started POST "/api/p/v1/users/verify" for 54.210.159.54 at 2020-12-04 09:48:11 +0000
2020-12-04T09:48:11.818319+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-04T09:48:11.818203 #16]  INFO -- : Processing by API::P::V1::UsersController#verify as JSON
2020-12-04T09:48:11.818504+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-04T09:48:11.818425 #16]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"login"=>"long token....................."}
2020-12-04T09:48:11.892237+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-04T09:48:11.892151 #16]  INFO -- : Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.35ms)
2020-12-04T09:48:11.892681+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-04T09:48:11.892583 #16]  INFO -- : Completed 400 Bad Request in 74ms (Views: 22.9ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)
2020-12-04T09:48:11.893186+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-04T09:48:11.893118 #16]  INFO -- : source=rack-timeout id=89c370e4-54e2-4442-83b2-d0c19b67c027 wait=6ms timeout=15000ms service=145ms state=completed
2020-12-04T09:48:11.894875+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/p/v1/users/verify" host=rails-api-app.herokuapp.com request_id=89c370e4-54e2-4442-83b2-d0c19b67c027 fwd="54.210.159.54" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=151ms status=400 bytes=406 protocol=https
```

**Server side:**

and the `Encryptable` module with the `Login` class and `Decode` module:

```
module RailsAppName
  module Encryptable
    class Login
      def self.decode(encrypted_payload, secret)
        begin
          new(Decoder.decode(encrypted_payload, secret))
          rescue JWT::DecodeError
            new({ valid: false, error_message: 'Invalid login information.' })
          rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature
            new({ valid: false, error_message: 'The signature has expired.' })
        end
      end
    end

    module Decoder
      DECODER              = JWT
      EXPIRATION           = 10
      ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "HS512"
    
      def self.decode(encrypted_payload = {}, secret = "")
        DECODER.decode(
          encrypted_payload,
          secret,
          ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM
        ).first
      end
    
      def self.encode(payload = {}, secret = "")
        prepare!(payload)
    
        DECODER.encode(
          payload,
          secret,
          ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM
        )
      end
    
      private
    
      def self.prepare!(payload)
        payload.merge! exp: expiration_time
      end
    
      def self.expiration_time
        EXPIRATION.minutes.from_now.to_i
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Client side:**

```
def verify(email, password)
  payload = { email: email, password: password }
  encrypted_payload = { login: RubyClient::JWTEncryptable.encode(payload) }.to_json
    
  response = public_client.post('/users/verify', { body: encrypted_payload })

  if response.code == 200
    { user_token: RubyClient::JWTEncryptable.encode(response["user"]), user: response["user"] }
  else
    { error: response['message'] }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the [ruby-jwt documentation](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) thoroughly.

Changing the `decode` method to the following works for me:

```
module Decoder
  DECODER              = JWT
  EXPIRATION           = 10
  ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = { algorithm: 'HS512' }

  def self.decode(encrypted_payload = {}, secret = "")
    DECODER.decode(
      encrypted_payload,
      secret,
      true,
      ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM
    ).first
  end
end
```